# How do I get the newest N files in a directory without getting all the other files too that I don't need?

Tags: php

I currently have this function:

```
function getUploadedImages() {
    $dir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads';
    $images = glob("$dir/*.{jpg,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);

    usort($images, function($a,$b){
        return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);
    });

    return array_slice($images, 0, 10);
}
```

At the start of the function, the `$images` array will contain every single file in the `uploads` directory.

Is there a way to avoid this, so that `glob()` won't have to return 100.000 files or more as the `uploads` folder grows?

I only need the newest N files, so it seems unnecessary to get all the other files that I don't need

Comment: Do you store details of the uploads in a database, this would allow you to select them by upload date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot avoid retrieving all file names using e.g. `glob`, then filtering the list to find the most recent ones.

However, even if it were possible, the way you are storing the uploaded files may cause problems in the future. If you *really* expect files numbering in the hundreds of thousands, the `glob` will get slower as the file system has trouble churning through the many files in the same directory.

May I suggest that you put uploaded files in subdirectories according to year, month, and (if needed) day? You would have a structure like:

```
- 2019
  - 12
    - 18
     - file1.jpg
     - file2.jpg
    - 19
     - file3.jpg
     - file4.jpg
```

In this case, finding the most recent files is a case of finding the most recent date, walking through the directory tree, and getting the filenames. If you need more files, pick the next earlier date and so on. If you're looking for the 10 most recent files or so, this process should be faster than globbing a very long list of files.

In addition, this approach does not require a database.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to avoid this

No it is not. Underlying filesystem does not provide this type of information so whatever way you go you (even with ordinary `ls`) you will have to scan all the items in given directory. However, if these files are stored there by you, you can store this information i.e. in database or flat file and then, use that "index" file for your task instead of touching physical files.